# How to cast nil to IOKit.IOHIDValueCallback in swift

Tags: xcode, macos, swift3, iokit

I write a small utility in swift which registers a callback using `IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback`. I am trying to be a good citizen and cleanup after myself.

The [documentation] (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/new_api_10_5/tn2187.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000970-CH214-SW61) says that to unregister one should call the registration function with `Null`

> Note: To unregister pass NULL for the callback.

unfortunately

```
IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback( hidManager, nil , nil);
```

doesn't compile saying :

> Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'IOHIDValueCallback' (aka '@convention(c) (Optional, Int32, Optional, IOHIDValue) -> ()')

How can I cast nil to the correct type ?

Here is a sample code which should compile :

```
import Foundation
import Carbon
import IOKit
import IOKit.usb
import IOKit.hid
class IOEventManager{
  func start()->Void{
    let hidManager = IOHIDManagerCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, IOOptionBits(kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone) );
    let context = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque());
    IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback( hidManager, nil, context);
  }
}
```

if you want a full project, checkout https://github.com/jeantil/autokbisw and look at [IOKeyEventMonitor#deinit](https://github.com/jeantil/autokbisw/blob/master/autokbisw/IOKeyEventMonitor.swift#L58)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long while I opened that project again and while perusing the method signature again, I noticed that the signature of the swift binding actually expects an `IOHIDValueCallback?` which means an optional `IOHIDValueCallback`

```
@available(OSX 10.5, *)
public func IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback(_ manager: IOHIDManager, _ callback: IOKit.IOHIDValueCallback?, _ context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
```

This was not obviously apparent to me because you can directly pass the `IOHIDValueCallback` value without explicit wrapping when calling the method.

Noticing this made the solution obvious :

```
IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback( hidManager, Optional.none , context);
```

The program now compiles and seems to behave properly.